# findContours(OpenCV) vs. regionprops(Matlab)

Tags: matlab, opencv

My final purpose is to calculate moments of all connected regions in image.

Problem: Regions storage methods in OpenCV and Matlab are different. It is clear that moments of regions and contours are different too.

So if I want to get result of extracting regions in Matlab:

```
test = imread('test.bmp');    
l = bwlabel(test, 8);
```

it is necessary follow code (OpenCV):

```
vector<vector<Point>> contours; 
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

Mat test = imread("..\\test.bmp", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
findContours(test , contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP , CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
for ( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
{
    if (hierarchy[i][3] > -1)
               continue;
    Mat imProcessing = Mat::zeros(test .size(), test .type());
    drawContours(imProcessing, contours, i, Scalar(255), CV_FILLED, 8, hierarchy, 1);
// now imProcessing contain connected region, not contour!
}
```

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: You should be clear about what you ask. If you are asking "how to find moments, given contours?", this is what you are looking for: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=moments#moments. If you are asking about efficiency (want to optimize the code): no, this is the most efficient way.